# Grid flex end not acting the way I expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to put two buttons under each other on the right. Here's my code:

```
export const WalletsContainer = () => {
  return (
    <Grid style={{ background: 'red' }} direction={'column'} alignItems={'flex-end'}>
      <Grid xs={2}>
        <CustomButton buttonText={t('add')} onClick={() => console.log('Add')} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid xs={2}>
        <CustomButton buttonText={t('download')} onClick={() => console.log('Download')} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

My question is, why is it now to the right? Based on the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive) `alignItems={'flex-end'}` should do the trick. Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: You should use `justifyContent="flex-end"` instead of `alignItems`.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela this still doesn't help. Why should it work? It's against the docs. Are they out of date?

Comment: I think you are missing `container` prop in `Grid`. Once you add `container` prop it will at `display: flex` style and then it will work like expected. In docs you shared there is `container` props available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <Grid container style={{ background: 'red' }} direction={'column'} alignItems={'flex-end'}>
```

Should do the trick.

from the docs - container -
If true, the component will have the flex container behavior. You should be wrapping items with a container.